One-column main text and two-column bibliography in revtex4-2 using \begin{thebibliography}
I need to create a document in revtex4-2 that uses the one-column format for the main text but typesets the bilbiography in a two-column layout. I tried using "\twocolumngrid" before the bilbiography command, but it seems that this does not allow for line breaks of long bilbiography entries as illustrated in the MWE below.
\documentclass[prd,amsmath,groupedaddress,onecolumn,eqsecnum,nofootinbib]{revtex4-2}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]

\cite{ref1}
\cite{ref2}

\twocolumngrid  

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{ref1} Reference 1
    \bibitem{ref2} Reference 2 which is so long that it splits across mutliple lines in the two column format.
    \bibitem{ref3} Reference 3
    \bibitem{ref4} Reference 4 which is so long that it splits across mutliple lines in the two column format.
    \bibitem{ref5} Reference 5
    \bibitem{ref6} Reference 6 which is so long that it splits across mutliple lines in the two column format.
    \bibitem{ref7} Reference 7
    \bibitem{ref8} Reference 8 which is so long that it splits across mutliple lines in the two column format.
    \bibitem{ref9} Reference 9
    \bibitem{ref10} Reference 10 which is so long that it splits across mutliple lines in the two column format.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

